How to create an Arc Button in flutter?
Im trying to create a ring of custom buttons in flutter.
It should look like a ring of 6 ring segments and each segment should be a button. (Optimal behavior would be if it grows a little outward when hovered).
I used a custom painter widget to draw one of the segments as the button shape but currently I'm struggling to handle the on tap because it triggers not only on the shape but in the whole bounding box of the arc.
Also the button text has no curvature to it.
I feel like there should be a package for control widgets like that..
If you could give me a hint to where I can find advice or give me code snippet if be really thankful!
Thanks in advance!
Edit: Added image


Please share image that you want to create.

You could checkout radial_button package

@DroidFlutter added a picture, the blue arc should act like a button

You Can Create it using Custompainter.
Adjust the start angle, stroke according to you needs 
 MaterialApp(
      home: Center(
        child: CustomPaint(
          size: Size(200, 200), // Specify the size of the canvas
          painter: CustomArcPainter(
            color: Colors.blue,
            startAngle: -0.7, // Start angle in radians
            sweepAngle: 3.14 / 2, // Sweep angle in radians (e.g., 90 degrees)
            strokeWidth: 8.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class CustomArcPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color color;
  final double startAngle; // Start angle in radians
  final double sweepAngle; // Sweep angle in radians
  final double strokeWidth;

  CustomArcPainter({
    required this.color,
    required this.startAngle,
    required this.sweepAngle,
    this.strokeWidth = 4.0,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    // Define the rectangle where the arc will be drawn
    final rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    // Draw the arc
    canvas.drawArc(
      rect,
      startAngle, // Counterclockwise rotation
      -sweepAngle, // Negative sweep angle for counterclockwise
      false, // Don't draw a full circle (arc only)
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}


Thank you for your reply! While this works awesome for the drawing of the arc, unfortunately the handling of the gesture detector recognizes the tap on the whole canvas (200*200) do you have any advice to adjust it?
